# In Django ,how can I save or update datetime of datetime field with db time?

Tags: python, mysql, django, datetime

db "T" with a table which have a datetime field ,for instance ,

```
CREATE TABLE `exec_job` (
  `job_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `finish_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`job_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

is in one machine, e.g. machine IP is 192.168.0.100.

My Django App "M" is in another one machine ,e.g. machine IP is 192.168.0.200,
the app M use the db T.

when I save or update data to db , I discover the "create_time" field and the "finish_time" field use the time of 192.168.0.200 to save . 
while ,**how can I save or update datetime of datetime field with db time in my Django app code?**

The Models Class like this:

```
class ExecJob(models.Model):
    JobId       = models.AutoField(db_column = "job_id", primary_key = True)
    Status      = models.IntegerField(db_column = "status", default = 0)
    CreateTime  = models.DateTimeField(db_column = "create_time", auto_now_add = True)
    FinishTime  = models.DateTimeField(db_column = "finish_time", auto_now = True)
    class Meta :
        db_table = "exec_job"
```

the app code like this:

```
jobobj = ExecJob(
    #JobId = models.AutoField(db_column = "job_id", primary_key = True)
    Status      = 0,
    #CreateTime = ,               # be commented
    #FinishTime = timezone.now(), # be commented
)
jobobj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following method in your Model Class

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.CreateTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.FinishTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    return super(ExecJob, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can "datetime.datetime.now()"  get the time of 192.168.0.100 ?@Vikas Neha Ojha

Comment: Nopes sorry. I got confused a bit. Let me work on it again and post an appropriate answer.

Comment: Do you want to do it through app only? Could you set up something default in the database?

Comment: the "create_time" can use auto update ,but the "finish_time" need real time update, I don`t know about mysql DB can realize this Function or not.

Comment: The "create_time" can be set in the database, but the "finish_time" need be updated in app .